# Using ItemSource in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having trouble getting a list to bind to my ListBox.  Here's the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Rocky.Data;

namespace Rocky.UI.Wpf
{
    using System.Windows;

    internal partial class ShellWindow : Window
    {
        public ShellWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new ShellViewModel();
        }

        public static ReadOnlyCollection<AuthorInformation> AuthorList
        {
            get { return AuthorRepository.Authors; }
        }


        public ShellViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return DataContext as ShellViewModel; }
            set { DataContext = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

AuthorRepository.Authors is just a ReadOnlyCollection created from an IList.  I can paste that code if need be, but I'm pretty sure the error is not in that class.  Then, here's the ListBox:

```
<ListBox 
    Name="AuthorListBox" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Margin="3" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Background="Cornsilk" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AuthorList}">
</ListBox>
```

I don't get an error at compile, or at runtime.  But, the ListBox does not fill up.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've looked through a lot of other posts here. Nothing so far has helped.

Comment: Most probably your data context is not set up properly (this causes errors to be written to the debugger output). Try to add `DataContext = this;` to the constructor.

Comment: You bind the listbox to `DataContext.AuthorList` and your DataContext is bound to a ShellViewModel. Does your ShellViewModel contain such a List?

Comment: Check your output window for errors in binding. will give clear picture what all are binding errors in your solution. best of luck for your interview too.

Comment: Lucas.  I had tried that already based on another post here I found.  It did not work.  But, good idea.  Thank you.

Comment: Sir Rufo - -ah ha!  I moved the definition for AuthorList into ShellViewModel, and at last, I am getting some movement.  Now, the list box fills up multiple instances of the namespace.  That's something!  I suspect now I need to set the text value?  Or, something?

Comment: Abin, thank you!  And, thank you!  I finally figured out how to ask this question so it got some feedback, and didn't get a bunch of down votes :-)

Comment: By default the listbox presents every item by calling the items `ToString()` method You can override the method `AuthorInformation.ToString()` or use a DataTemplate

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm off to google ListBox DataTemplates.

Comment: Please remind that SO did not offer a question blog. It is only Question and Answer. Ask **one** question and do not change this question into a new one!

Comment: thanks.  Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthorList` property should be in the `ShellViewModel` class.